# 10.9.5 mac pro - cannot ssh out

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

I cannot ssh to any server.

```
ssh -vvv joe@ip


OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/joe/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ip port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ip port 22: Connection refused
```

.ssh/config (pushing/pulling git works fine)

```
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
```

ssh_config

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

something strange, I can't SSH to anything however, github works and if I use the "ssh" button in google cloud, it will connect to the server from there.  something wrong with my terminal?

something that maybe important, in the known hosts file, the ports are all 443

when checking logs on the server, no attempt is ever noted for my ipaddress, so my request never hits the server.

[UPDATE]

took the laptop home and tried it, logged in no problem.  so its not the computer, its not the server, its not the router because I skipped it.  verizon and our office line must use the same backbone in the area.  its something with the lines there.  not good!  I'll let anyone know if/when I figure out more, thanks for help everyone.

Comment: i've manually added the entry to the known hosts, but still no luck.  port 22 is open on the server and sshd is listening.

Comment: How you tried loggin in as another user on your machine and SSH from there? There might be something wrong/strange/funny with your .ssh config.

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but I should also note that the servers that i've been unable to connect to (verified) are centos 6 / 7

Comment: What does `telnet ip 22` output?,

Comment: trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx telnet: connect to address xxx..xxx: connection refused  telnet: unable to connect to remote host

Comment: @cousinCocaine using a different account had no effect

Comment: So if login in from your Mac as a different user (lets say the Guest account) and than log in to the server did not work? And you are convinced the server is working and no firewall is up? And what about a SFTP login? Or using another machine to test the connection (like your phone)

Comment: Ping? I think something is blocking your connection. And the error is not on your machine. Mightbe you have `fail2ban` or alike software installed.

Comment: ping works fine, nothing lost.  logging on as a different user still did not allow login (i did put key on server) the only way I can access it is from the google console 'ssh' button.

Comment: What does `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getglobalstate` output?

Comment: @MaxRied Firewall is disabled. (State=0) also tried from phone, and would not go through

Comment: Is your phone connected through cellular network? Or to the same network as your computer is?

Comment: verizon network

Comment: Your computer is connected via a landline?

Comment: t1 line - no router

Comment: i tried changing port 22 to other ports and still get the same, connection refused from the mac